Notation on fourier transforms
For a function $x(t)$ which has a fourier transform $X(j\omega)$:
If I do this...
$$X(-j\omega) \tag 1 $$
What does this notation mean then? Do I make every $j$ negative in the transfer function, every $\omega$? Or do I only turn $j\omega$ to $-j\omega$ in the transfer function?

While commonplace, $X(j\omega)$ is (in my opinion) a kind of sloppy notation and I prefer $X(\omega)$ which is  much cleaner.

Why not stick with the Laplace Transform?  Do you never expect to write $H(s)$?

When I'm doing strictly Fourier in the continuous-time domain, I wanna take advantage of duality.  So then it's $x(t)$ and $X(f)$.

This notation isn't special to the Fourier transform.  It's just how functions are treated.  $X(\cdot)$ is a function of its argument.  If you call out $X(j\omega)$, then that means "look everywhere you see "$j\omega$" and plug in the value you want.
So, yes -- in this context, $X(-j\omega)$ means take any $j\omega$ in $X(j\omega)$ and replace it with $-j\omega$ (and replace $-j\omega$ with $j\omega$, and $\omega^2$ with $\omega^2$, because $(-j\omega)^2 = -\omega^2 = (j\omega)^2$, so $\omega^{2n}$ remains unchanged.
